# Express-Mongoose how to pass multiple collections to view

Tags: express, mongoose, ejs

I am trying to pass multiple mongoDB queries to my EJS view with the code bellow but for some reason only the "mvl" gets passed down. "extras" remains unavailable (can't make any of the values show up on view) and at the same time throws no errors when I try to load my view (doesn't say "Extras is undefined".

```
router.get("/mvl", function(req, res) {
    index.find({}, function(err, mvl) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            extra.find({}, function(err, extras) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(extras);
                }
                res.render("index", { mvl: mvl, extras: extras });
            });
        }

    });
```

What need to be done in order to make this work?

Cheers,

Ian

Answer (score 0):

Figured how to pass extras collection like this

```
router.get("/mvl", function(req, res) {
    index.find({}, function(err, mvl) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {

            extra.find({}, function(err, extras) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(extras);
                    res.render("index", { mvl: mvl, extras: extras });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The collection is an array so you want to call the information like this in your ejs

<%= extras[0].youStuff %>